# how to refresh a tableview when click a button on tableviewcell

Tags: uitableview, swift

there's a tableviewcontroller, and there's an array in it contains the content show on tableviewcell, when I click the button on cell, I need to modify the array in tableviewcontroller and refresh tableview, how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject){
          //edit the array
          myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: 1. how can I get myTableView? 2. I need to modify the array in tableviewcontroller first. so it seems not work.

Comment: You can try to implement a delegate for that, or use NSNotificationCenter to notify the tableViewController when the button is pressed. @ArthurWu

Comment: It might be a good advice, I'll try, thx.